# How to write a escape sequence for "(" and ")" in java

Tags: java, escaping

I have a query where i am using

```
select   
concat(jo.title, "(" ,CCP.name,")"),
```

for the result .My expected result is Java Developer(Morgan Stanley) this way .So how can i write it in java file .For now i am using

```
+" concat(jo.title ," + "\"(\""+",CCP.name )"+"\")\""+"\") ,"
```

I am doing this for right bracket ,but it is not coming ,please anybody help

Comment: Use ` \\\` instead of `\\`

Comment: can you write it i am not getting

Comment: Usually in SQL the correct quotes are single quotes. Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try " concat(jo.title ," + "\"(\""+",CCP.name) ,"